# Not able to extract complete city list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using the following code to extract the list of cities mentioned on this page, but it gives me just the first 23 cities.
Can't figure out where I am going wrong!

```
import requests,bs4
res=requests.get('http://www.citymayors.com/statistics/largest-cities-population-125.html')
text=bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
fields=text.select('td[bgcolor="silver"] > font[size="-2"] > b')
print len(fields)
for field in fields:
    print field.getText()
```

This is the output I am getting:

```
23
Tokyo/Yokohama
New York Metro
Sao Paulo
Seoul/Incheon
Mexico City
Osaka/Kobe/Kyoto
Manila
Mumbai
Delhi
Jakarta
Lagos
Kolkata
Cairo
Los Angeles
Buenos Aires
Rio de Janeiro
Moscow
Shanghai
Karachi
Paris
Istanbul
Nagoya
Beijing
```

But this webpage contains 125 cities.

Comment: Using `html.parser` instead of `lxml`, I get 124

Comment: I too get 124. The missing city is Damman on row 120. Might have something to do with the space `<font size="-2" face="Arial">Damman </font>` ?

Answer (score 0):

*lxml* works fine for me, I get 124 cities using your own code so it has nothing to do with the parser, you are either using an old version of *bs4* or it is an encoding issue, you should  call *.content* and  let requests handle the encoding, you are also missing a city using your logic, to get all 125:

```
import requests, bs4
res = requests.get('http://www.citymayors.com/statistics/largest-cities-population-125.html')
text = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.content,"lxml")
rows = [row.select_one("td + td")for row in text.select("table tr + tr")]
print(len(rows))
for row in rows:
    print(row.get_text())
```

If we run it, you can see we get all the cities:

```
In [1]: import requests,bs4
In [2]: res = requests.get('http://www.citymayors.com/statistics/largest-cities-population-125.html')

In [3]: text = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")

In [4]: rows = [row.select_one("td + td")for row in text.select("table tr + tr")]   
In [5]: print(len(rows))
125    
In [6]: for row in rows:
   ...:         print(row.get_text())
   ...:     
Tokyo/Yokohama
New York Metro
Sao Paulo
Seoul/Incheon
Mexico City
Osaka/Kobe/Kyoto
Manila
Mumbai
Delhi
Jakarta
Lagos
Kolkata
Cairo
Los Angeles
Buenos Aires
Rio de Janeiro
Moscow
Shanghai
Karachi
Paris
Istanbul
Nagoya
Beijing
Chicago
London
Shenzhen
Essen/Düsseldorf
Tehran
Bogota
Lima
Bangkok
Johannesburg/East Rand
Chennai
Taipei
Baghdad
Santiago
Bangalore
Hyderabad
St Petersburg
Philadelphia
Lahore
Kinshasa
Miami
Ho Chi Minh City
Madrid
Tianjin
Kuala Lumpur
Toronto
Milan
Shenyang
Dallas/Fort Worth
Boston
Belo Horizonte
Khartoum
Riyadh
Singapore
Washington
Detroit
Barcelona
Houston
Athens
Berlin
Sydney
Atlanta
Guadalajara
San Francisco/Oakland 
Montreal.
Monterey
Melbourne
Ankara
Recife
Phoenix/Mesa
Durban
Porto Alegre
Dalian
Jeddah
Seattle
Cape Town
San Diego
Fortaleza
Curitiba
Rome
Naples
Minneapolis/St. Paul
Tel Aviv
Birmingham
Frankfurt
Lisbon
Manchester
San Juan
Katowice
Tashkent
Fukuoka
Baku/Sumqayit
St. Louis
Baltimore
Sapporo
Tampa/St. Petersburg
Taichung
Warsaw
Denver
Cologne/Bonn
Hamburg
Dubai
Pretoria
Vancouver
Beirut
Budapest
Cleveland
Pittsburgh
Campinas
Harare
Brasilia
Kuwait
Munich
Portland
Brussels
Vienna
San Jose
Damman 
Copenhagen
Brisbane
Riverside/San Bernardino
Cincinnati
Accra
```